# Broadcast Receiver doesn't work in Android 10

Tags: c#, service, xamarin.android, background, broadcastreceiver

I have some problem with BroadcastReceiver implement in my Xamarin project. I want to restart my service when the user reboot device. In particular it works fine in OxygenOS (OnePlus 6T) but not in Android 10 "Vanilla" (Samsung Galaxy A7 2018). I have tried also with Visula Studio Emulator, both with Android 9.0 and Android 10.0, and it works well. I don't understand why it doesn't work on my device. This is my implementation of BroadcastReceiver:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] {Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
    public class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            try
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context, "It's work", ToastLength.Long).Show();

                Intent downloadIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(DemoIntentService));
                downloadIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                context.StartService(downloadIntent);

                Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, typeof(TestIntent));
                intent2.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                context.StartService(intent2);
            }
            catch
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context, "Not works", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }

        }

    }
```

Then I show you the Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<application ...
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="crc64a8a173fc3f8c46da.BootReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: Compare working and non working response.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Not yet .. Do you know how to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 2022 ANSWER - I USE BROADCAST RECEIVER TO RESCHEDULE MY LOCAL NOTIFICATIONS

After almost 3 hours banging my head on the wall, I finally got it to work. All answers are out dated since Google made a few API changes. Anyway, here is what worked for me.

### How I tested

1. Launch App on phone (Just to clear out any confusions, I even launched it using my IDE debugger. I can confirm 'debug' mode has no effect on boot receivers). Fyi, I am using Xiaomi Pocophone F1. My App is targeting API level 30.
2. Make the App schedule notifications to appear 3 minutes later
3. Reboot the phone
4. Wait for 3 minutes (Note that I am NOT launching my App. I also do not have App autostart permission enabled for me. There was some old answer suggesting autostart must be on. This is WRONG i.e. not required)
5. After 3 minutes  the notification appears! This means during reboot the Boot BroadcastReceiver fired up.

### The code

```
[assembly: UsesPermission (Manifest.Permission.ReceiveBootCompleted)]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    [BroadcastReceiver(Name = "com.myapp.whatever.BootReceiver", Enabled = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]    
    public class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            RescheduleNotifications();
        }

        public void RescheduleNotifications()
        {
            try
            {
                AppCenter.Start("android=cfc33334-8f5e-4ab3-1232-e8712345c860;"
                    //"ios={Your iOS App secret here}",
                    , typeof(Crashes));
                
                //Make sure all services are instantiated
                AppCore.DeviceService = new DeviceService();
                AppCore.FbService = new FBService();
                AppCore.AppService = new AppService();
                AppCore.DeviceService.ScheduleNotifications(notif.Notifications, false);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(e);
            }
        
        }
    }
}
```

### Notes on my code

- I am using MS App Center to track crashes. You may omit these parts.
- Remember that the OnReceive is fired alone (without Main Activity being fired). So make sure your code can run and does not throw any exceptions.
- In "com.myapp.whatever.BootReceiver" replace "com.myapp.whatever" with your app's package name

### The android manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
<application ....>
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.myapp.whatever.BootReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

### Other things to note

- There is no need to 'Initialize' the BootReceiver in MainActivity. As long as you set the BroadcasrReceiver Attribute and Android Manifest, it's all good.
- Please ensure the broadcast receiver does not encounter any exception. This is the part which I did not see. Track the Crashes to see if it throws any exceptions. I use AppCenter.ms for this. You can see my code above.